# Django default_from_email name

Tags: django, django-settings, django-email

I am looking to add a name to my default_from_email address in Django and wanted to know whether you do this through the settings.py file?

you have your different options.

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
EMAIL_HOST
EMAIL_PASSWORD
...
```

but the email result still ends in from: `noreply@mydomain.com` and I would like to change this into `My Domain` instead.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

set [**`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-from-email)

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'My Domain <noreply@mydomain.com>'
```

Comment: IS there any reason why Django requires EMAIL_FROM setting to be set, but in the same time only DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL is being used?

Comment: @TheGodfather Which version that django requires EMAIL_FROM?
I have looked at the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings since version 1.8 until 3.1 (now), that EMAIL_FROM settings not found.

Comment: @aijogja it was 3 years ago, I don't even remember =) But as my comment got a few upvotes, I assume I was not the only one getting this inconsistency. Maybe it was fixed in the meantime, maybe it was some undocumented behavior, who knows...