# How do I set the from_email var

Tags: django, amazon-ses

I'm trying to use Amazon's SES and the Django-ses app to send emails.  It works locally but fails on the server, returning the SESAddressNotVerifiedError.

Inspecting the trace revealed that it's failing because the from_email var is set to webmaster@localhost.  I've looked all over to find where I set this variable to my verified email address in AWS-SES.

Does anyone know how I am supposed to change the from_email var from webmaster@localhost to myemail@myemail.com?

Thanks,

Anthony

Comment: You can test it using the `send_mail()` method and setting `from_email` parameter just like django-ses indicates [Django-ses](https://github.com/hmarr/django-ses#django-builtin-in-error-emails)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out that what I needed to change was this setting:

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'My Domain < myEmail@myEmail.com >'

For everyone who is using [Django-Registrations](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) this is the default, but the reference to it is in registration/models.py, line 264 (the last line) if you want to change it, which I might unless it breaks, in which case, I'll report back.

[Django default_from_email name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744680/django-default-from-email-name)

Thanks to [Ashok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223892/ashok) for this solution