# Django-allauth sends verification emails from webmaster@<servername>

Tags: email, django-allauth

How can I set custom email address to be used in "From:" section of all emails, which a sended by django-allauth to users?

By default, users receives emails from `webmaster@name_of_my_ubuntu_server` - it looks ugly. I want to use something like `info@website.com`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add the following line to your `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "info@website.com"
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this information surprisingly hard to locate in the documentation.

Comment: This is actually part of Django's own settings but it is confusing anyway; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#default-from-email

Comment: thanks! and for those who are looking to customize the name as well, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744728) TLDR: `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "John <john@example.com>"`